# Is it "financial and real estate industry" or "financial and real estate industries"?

Tags: differences

Is it "financial and real estate industry" or "financial and real estate industries"?

I'm trying to figure out which example is correct. Are they synonymous?

Context: In the sentence, both are being used as completely separate industries. The alternative (and longer) form is to write "financial industry and real estate industry". If I were to combine the two (using a single noun and two adjectives instead of two nouns and two adjectives), how would I properly combine them?

Saying "financial and real estate industries" seems to suggest that there are multiple financial industries and real estate industries.

Saying "financial and real estate industry" seems to suggest that I am discussing an industry that combines both the financial industry and real estate industry. However, that is not the intent. The intent is to write "financial industry and real estate industry" in a shortened form (if possible).

Comment: What context are you using it in? Both can be correct; it depends on whether you see them as a single combined industry or as two separate ones.

Comment: "both are being used as completely separate industries" <-- I think that you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Saying "financial and real estate industries" seems to suggest that there are multiple financial industries and real estate industries.

*Could* it be used to mean that there were multiple industries of each kind? Yes. But nobody would interpret it that way in most contexts.

Note that "the financial and real estate industries" does not mean "the financial industries and the real estate industries"; this isn't a case of ellipsis.

Comment: Syntacto-semantically, "the financial and real estate industries" could well mean "the financial industries and the real estate industries".